# Content type query in webpart

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part

Other than Content Query webpart - is there any other OOB webpart that can query a content type present in two different list ?

Or is there a way to use DataView webpart to retrieve contents from two or more lists ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the output you'd expect? You want to show yes/no if both lists contain items using a content type assigned to the list, or merely if the content type is assigned to both lists?

Comment: I just wanted to display few fields from a Content type - the Dave's answer (datasource = linking) solved my problem - so I used DV WP !  Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the core search results web part - this will work across the farm as opposed to a CQWP which is restricted to a site collection - but I find the search results harder to format that the CQWP.

In SPD it is also possible to merge data sources - ie lists.  An example is https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-Link-Two-Lists-and-Create-a-Combined-View-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx.  In this case you would then be able to use a DVWP.